# PC freezing when using browser after 10-15 min in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04. I never used Linux or Ubuntu before. When I am using browsers such as Firefox or Chrome, the PC freezes and can do nothing. I don't know how to fix it and I don't know why it's happening. Please support and explain to me how to fix the problem.